# Error: in the string to float conversion. float object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.6

My score are here where these are in a json file

```
"score": [0.7503408193588257, 0.43428170680999756]
```

the my code for making if to a string is like this:

```
score = data[model][id]["score"][0][index]
all = (class_info +" "+ str(score)+" "+x1+" "+y1+" "+x2+" "+y2+" "+"\n")
```

where *x1,y1,x2,y2 and class_info* are some variable.

and I am getting this type of error in python 3.6.9:

```
  File "convert_formet.py", line 28, in main_function
    score = data[model][id]["score"][0][index]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

some one help me out pls.

Comment: Regarding the line `score = data[model][id]["score"][0][index]`, you want either `[0]` or `[index]` at the end of it, but not both.  `data[model][id]["score"][0]` gives you the first float in the list, and then applying`[index]` to that is what is causing the error for exactly the reason given in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

@CryptoFool says me to do this:

```
score = data[model][id]["score"][0][index]
```

or this:

```
score = data[model][id]["score"][0][index]
```

So, I found my answer.

We should match the variable correctly. If not this type of errors will come.